# How does the JavaScript instanceOf method execute in this statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "words";
a instanceOf String;    
#=> false
```

I can't understand how this code snippet works.

- Is `instanceof` a method of `a`, or of `this` which locates it in the default scope?
- If `String` here is a parameter passed to `instanceof`, how come it doesn't have parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof` is an operator, so it's more like `+` than a function.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: It makes sense, but to be frank, this operator really strange to me

Comment: is a is not a a instance of String, what kind of instance it is, and how to use command to check it, something like `a.class` in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

[`instanceof` is an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) like `=` or `%`